# Mapbox Android WMTS Raster Source

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am trying to load rastersouce in map box but it was having error.

```
binding.mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) 
{ style ->
 
            style.addSource(
            rasterSource("maastokartta-source") {
                url("http://52.59.214.0/maanmittauslaitos/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/maastokartta/default/ETRS-TM35FIN/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
            })
            // Create a RasterLayer with the source created above and then add the layer to the map
            if (style.getLayer("tunnel-street-minor-low") != null) {
                style.addLayerBelow(
                    RasterLayer("maastokartta-layer", "maastokartta-source"),
                    "tunnel-street-minor-low"
                )
            } else {
                style.addLayer(RasterLayer("maastokartta-layer", "maastokartta-source"))
            }
 }
```

Error Logs

```
[maps-core]: {OnlineFileSourc}[General]: The resource http://52.59.214.0/maanmittauslaitos/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/maastokartta/default/ETRS-TM35FIN/{z}/{x}/{y}.png not found
[maps-core]: {droid.lctracker}[Style]: Failed to load source maastokartta-source: HTTP status code 404
[maps-android\Mbgl-StyleObserver]: OnMapLoadError: SOURCE, message: Failed to load source: HTTP status code 404, sourceID: maastokartta-source, tileID: null
```

Working Eg URL : http://52.59.214.0/maanmittauslaitos/avoin/wmts/1.0.0/maastokartta/default/ETRS-TM35FIN/0/0/0.png